# How to troubleshoot error while refreshing

Tags: powerbi

While refreshing data I get the error:  **OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E1D.**

I adjusted the settings so that only 1 file at a time is refreshed, and now I receive that error for the calendar file and all subsequent files show an error:  **Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table.**

I assume this means there was a problem with the calendar table, though it originally worked and nothing has been modified.

I hate to ask such vague questions, but where should I look to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Problem was originating from data model. Table's ID should have been distinct. After refreshed, It had changed. There was duplicated ID's. I deleted duplicated ID's and run it again. It refreshed.

Solving approach: To find the table causing problem, go to "transform data" right click table that you decided it can be duplicated, remove "enable load" tick, save and refresh. Do it until you find the table or TABLES.

If that is not a solution for you, check it out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/get-data/9-import-errors